# Scatterplot with latest available observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am finding some issues with creating a scatterplot based on the latest available observation per each variable. I would like to take the latest obs per each variable and each country and then compute the scatterplot. I created a short example with random number to show that in my infrastructure some countries are missing due to missing observation in the `df` table. The chart should take 2019q1 for NL and FR .

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(data.table)


# scatterplot preparation
set.seed(123)
country <- c("AT", "BE", "NL", "DE", "FR", "IT", "ES", "PT", "AT", "BE", "NL", "DE", "FR", "IT", "ES", "PT")
year <- as.yearqtr(c("2019 Q1", "2019 Q1","2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2"))

HPG <- runif(16, min=0, max=5)

HAR <- runif(16, min=-1, max=3)
HAR[c(11,13)] <- NA

df <- data.frame(country, year, HPG, HAR)
df <- as.data.table(df)

df2019q2 <- df[df$year == "2019 Q2"]

ggplot(data = df2019q2, aes(x = HAR, y = HPG, label = country)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = country),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
 theme_bw() + 
guides(linetype = FALSE, size = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "HPG", breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10), limits = c(-6, 4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "HAR", breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you'd like to replace only the missing value with previous information or take the last quarter for all values. Below are solutions with `data.table` and/or `zoo`.

*First scenario* - taking last quarter for all columns (i.e. both `HAR` and `HPG` in your case):

```
df2019q2 <- na.omit(df)[order(year), ][, .SD[.N], by = country]
```

Hereby we first remove all rows with any missing value with `na.omit`, then we `order` by `year`, and last but not least we take a subset of data (`.SD`) whereby only last row (`.N`) per each `country` is taken (as suggested by @Uwe, you could also use `last(.SD)` to get the last row and shorten this to `na.omit(df)[order(year), last(.SD), by = country]`.

The plot would look like:

[image]

*Second scenario* - Taking last observation of each column separately, e.g. we keep `MPG` for `2019Q2` and `HAR` for `2019Q1`.

You could use the `na.locf` from `zoo` to carry last observation forward in both `HPG` and `MPG` columns, e.g.:

```
df2019q2 <- df[, c("HPG", "HAR") := lapply(.SD, na.locf), by = country, .SDcols = c("HPG", "HAR")][year == "2019 Q2"]
```

Which would give the following plot:

[image]

This of course assumes that you want to replace missing values with information from any last quarter that had a non-missing value. For instance, if you'd have missing info for `2019Q2` and `2019Q1` but a non-missing value in `2018Q4` they would both get the value from `2018Q4`.

**Important**: In both cases you'd need to adjust your `ggplot` code to expand limits (otherwise you'd lose information again) - I've replaced `c(-6, 4)` with `c(-6, 6)`:

```
ggplot(data = df2019q2, aes(x = HAR, y = HPG, label = country)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = country),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50') +
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(linetype = FALSE, size = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "HPG", breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10), limits = c(-6, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "HAR", breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))
```

Comment: The OP has asked for the *latest available observation* and to *take 2019q1 for NL and FR* which is addressed by the first scenario only. (BTW, I was about to post a similar answer `na.omit(df)[order(year), last(.SD), by = country]`.)

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, `last(.SD)` is a good alternative as it doesn't make you wonder where the `.N` comes from if one isn't a regular `data.table` user .. As for the scenarios, I also think the first one is the right one, however OP started with *latest available observation per each variable* - which still makes me wonder whether he isn't after last observations separately per each variable. I'll remove the second part once we have OP's feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. What if I want to take the last available observation for HPG let's say that is 2019 Q1 and the last (relative to HPG) - 4 observation for HAR (I have quarterly data). So I should have 2019q1 for HPG and 2018q1 for HAR (i.e. even if latest available for HAR is 2019q3)?

Answer (score 0):

One approach using `tidyverse` is below.

You can `group_by` `country` since you are interested in latest value per country. Then, would `drop_na` to remove rows with missing values.

Make sure your data is arranged by year (since you want the latest value in terms of time). Finally, filter your data taking only the rows that contain the latest year.

```
library(tidyverse)

sub_data <- df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  filter(year == last(year))
```

You should be able to plot based on this filtered subset of data. Note that 2 observations are lost as they fall outside your limits (FR and PT).

[image: plot based on subset data]

Final note about removing `NA`. I noticed you use `data.table` and `zoo` libraries. You may be interested in an alternative to `drop_NA`. That could include `na.omit.data.table` (fast) or `complete.cases` or `na.omit`.